# .NET 6 exclude runtime assets of transitive dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-core, plugins, msbuild, dynamic-loading

I'm working on a plugin module for a .NET 6 app and I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support) Microsoft Docs guide, however I hit a problem while dynamically loading the plugin assemblies.

I want to achieve the following project structure:

- `SomeService.PluginBase`
- `SomeService` depends on `SomeService.PluginBase`
- `SomeService.PluginSdk` depends on `SomeService.PluginBase`
- `SomePlugin` depends on `SomeService.PluginSdk`

During startup, `SomeService` scans the configured assemblies for implementations of the `IPlugin` interface from the `SomeService.PluginBase` package. `SomeApi.PluginSdk` provides base classes for plugin implementations and reference to the previously mentioned interface transitively.

According to the guide, to avoid assembly mismatch I need to set

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeService.PluginBase\SomeService.PluginBase.csproj">
        <Private>false</Private>
        <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

in the project file of `SomeService.Sdk` to avoid copying the assembly to the output directory.
This works fine, however `SomeService.PluginBase` is still being copied to the output directory of `SomePlugin`, as it is a transitive dependency of `SomeService.Sdk`. Even though `IPlugin` is in `SomeService.PluginBase`, `SomeService` fails to load the plugin due to two different `IPlugin` types.

Is there a way to prevent this without explicitly listing `SomeService.PluginBase` as a `<ProjectReference>` of `SomePlugin`?

Comment: Not sure on why this is getting output, the documentation probably needs some clarification, or its a bug, as its the use case seems pretty straight forward (to me). However if understand the problem, likely the `IPlugin` interface should be in its own abstraction library, which may solve the problem. Additionally, if you can create the most minimal of reproducible example, it might be taking this to git hub... Either way, there is a case to be made for better documentation or a bug fix potentially